# Rest Web Service + Apache Solr: mostrar XML en webapi

Tags: java, webservice, apache, rest

tengo un problema y en parte es de desconocimiento. Estoy tratando que mi Web Service me muestre el XML correspondiente a los datos indexados en Apache Solr. EL WS está conectado, probado y obtiene los datos, pero a la hora de hacer el return para mostrar los datos en el resource solo me da unas etiquetas sin sentido en el código fuente.

Este sería el modelo "Producto":

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;

@XmlRootElement
public class Producto {

private String id;
private String name;
private String manu;
private String manu_id_s;
private SolrDocumentList results;

public Producto() {

}

public Producto(String id, String name, String manu, String manu_id_s) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.manu = manu;
    this.manu_id_s = manu_id_s;
}


public Producto(SolrDocumentList results) {
    this.results = results;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getManu() {
    return manu;
}

public void setManu(String manu) {
    this.manu = manu;
}

public String getManu_id_s() {
    return manu_id_s;
}

public void setManu_id_s(String manu_id_s) {
    this.manu_id_s = manu_id_s;
}



}
```

Su correspondiente servicio "ProductoService":

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;

import com.data.solr.PruebaMavenSolr3.conexion.Connection;
import com.data.solr.PruebaMavenSolr3.modelos.Producto;

public class ProductoService {

public List<Producto> getTodosProductos() throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
    Connection.init();
    final SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(); 
    query.setQuery("*:*");
    query.setIncludeScore(false);
    query.setFields("id,name,manu,manu_id_s");
    query.setParam("wt", "xml");
    QueryResponse response = Connection.server.query(query);
    Producto p1 = new Producto(response.getResults());
    List<Producto> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(p1);
    return list;

}
}
```

Y Su recurso "MyResource"

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;

import com.data.solr.PruebaMavenSolr3.modelos.Producto;
import com.data.solr.PruebaMavenSolr3.servicios.ProductoService;

@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

ProductoService productoService = new ProductoService();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Producto> getProductos() throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
    return productoService.getTodosProductos();
}
}
```

Al ejecutar el webapi me muestra una página vacía con este código fuente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><productoes><producto/></productoes>
```

Ya probé cambiando la configuración de muchas formas y no tengo un ejemplo claro de como trabajar Rest WS con Solr.

Muchas gracias.

**Actualización: como dato adicional dejo también la conexión a Solr. En el momento que conecta realiza un parseo a XML**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.XMLResponseParser;

public class Connection {
public static HttpSolrServer server;
public static void init() throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException{
    server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/");
    server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza este fragmento de codigo

```
    @XmlRootElement
    public class Producto
```

por el siguiente :

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Producto")
    public class Producto
```

Comment: Ya hice el cambio pero no hubo cambios. Al parecer no es un problema de mapeado. Saludos.